# Secure JSON Web Token in Web API / MVC 6

Tags: asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0, single-page-application, jwt, asp.net-core-mvc

The security concerns:
According to https://auth0.com/blog/2015/03/31/critical-vulnerabilities-in-json-web-token-libraries/ a lot of JWT libraries use the token itself in order to determine the algorithm for the signature.

This is our use case:
We want to create a login mechanism that validates a user with the hard credentials (username/password) and then return a JWT token with e.g. 3 Days lifetime. The token should contain the username and a signature should guarantee that the token cannot be "faked".

What library can we use in Web API / MVC 6? It is important that the signature algorithm can be specified on decoding to avoid the vulnerability.

If possible we would like to avoid integrating complex OAuth components.

Comment: After just little bit of googling I have found two interesting things: open source project on GitHub - jwt-dotnet: https://github.com/jwt-dotnet/jwt and JSON Web Token Handler for the Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5 on NuGet: https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt/ It look like both of them can offer generation and validation of JWT tokens, however I haven't used them,

Comment: I saw these. I do not know if they offer spec.of algo on validation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am using the `System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt` library, and I just checked for this issue. I Generated a token and validated it in one of my tests, then I removed the `signingCredentials` which changes the alg to none. The JWT generated with the `"alg":"none"` *failed validation*.

Here is how I am generating the token:

```
public string GenerateToken(SSOContext context, SignatureSettings settings)
{
    var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
        issuer: "MyIssuer",
        audience: "MyAudience",
        claims: GetClaims(context),
        //comment the below line to generate a 'none' alg
        signingCredentials: new X509SigningCredentials(settings.Certificate),
        notBefore: DateTime.UtcNow,
        expires: DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(1)
        );

    return new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);
}
```

When I validate the token I get an exception as expected with the message

> IDX10504: Unable to validate signature, token does not have a
>   signature:

Comment: As I read the comments in the net about the vulnerability the only way to be on the safe side would be to define the expected algo on validation hardcoded. Is this possible with this library?  At Least it would not be vulnerable to the none algo issue as I understand your response. Maybe you can confirm or add additional information.

Comment: You can take the jwt and turn it into a JwtSecurityToken object and check the SignatureAlgorithm property to make sure it is what is expected as well. If not you could not even bother validating and just reject it. [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.identitymodel.tokens.jwtsecuritytoken(v=vs.114).aspx) If you see anything wrong, please let me know. I am answering partly to see if anyone spots an error.

Comment: This all looks reasonable and solid to me I think I am going to accept your answer very soon. I am not sure if I can fully test until the bounty ends. So I guess I need to accept it then soon in order to prevent loss of the award.